# Calling controller function after facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm currently new to facebook login, so what I did was I created a simple button that would call the `getLoginUrl()` function. However, after I was asked by facebook if I was willing to share my info, etc., It goes to an error 404 page.

I used Facebook PHP SDK, and if from what I read from google results, I think I should have a callback function or something. How do I integrate that?

```
<?php   $user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
    try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
    $user = null;
    }
    } 
if ($user) {    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    }   
?>

 <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with facebook</a>
```

That's basically what I've done to call the faceboook api and have my login.
What should I add to make it go the a controller function that I want? I am using codeigniter as my PHP framework.

Answer (score 1):

you should add `redirect_uri` to redirect users after login like:

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'email',
   'redirect_uri' => base_url(). 'some_controller/some_function', // Replace with your function
);
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

See this:: [Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/)

Comment: Just tried that but it still shows an error 404 even if I have already have added the controller function. Did I forget something?